# R bug (?) returns NaN in function x^0.88 but not per hand

Tags: r, function

I am using R 3.2.3 and this happens: a function returns NaN but the same code by hand returns the correct result.

Can somebody explain this behavior to me?

```
func <- function(x)
{
    return(x^0.88)
}
func(-1) # [1] NaN

-1^0.88 # [1] -1
```

Comment: A quick comment: suspecting a bug in the language should be the very last step in your debugging procedure :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-1^0.88` parses as `-(1^0.88)`. That should be `(-1)^0.88` to match the function.

See `?Syntax` for operator precedence in R.